# Is the css html footer question possible to resolve?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have some major problems centering the footer text vertically (height) and I do want the footer to be closer to the paragraph text. Is this possible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arDt9.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylefooter.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<p>ffsdergserkghretkguhsritg</p></br>
</div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
<p>Ohhhh yeah!</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

- {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

  html, body {
      height: 100%;
  }

  ## container {

  ```
  min-height: 100%;
  ```

  }

  ## main {

  ```
  overflow: auto;             
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  ```

  }

  ## footer {

  ```
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;               
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  ```

  }

Comment: Does `v-align:center` work?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better assist you.

Comment: Post some code...

Comment: Sorry I am novice omn this and the form was not happy camper today.

Comment: Solved the secord of the two part question. I managed (on my own) to move footer closer to the top. Now, is it possible to center the text vertically? I have tried v-align but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property "line-height" in css and put the height of the footer as value

```
footer 
{
    height : 40px;
}

footer > p 
{
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

more information : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height